# Ajax pagination with filters in cakephp

Tags: cakephp-2.0

Can anybody give a best example of ajax pagination in cakephp 2.x.

This should include data filtering also.

I have read cakephp manual but could not understand much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long search and work, i have developed a solution which is as follows:

Client Side:

- Fist of all create a form with all filtering options.
- Submit the form using ajax.
- Use Post method to submit the form.
- Submit the form using serialize method.

Server Side:

- All filter form data will be available in $this->request->data.
- Set PaginatorHelper options as mentioned below:

  $this->paginator->options(array(

  ```
  'url' => $this->passedArgs,

  'update' => 'element_id_to_be_updated',
  'evalScripts' => true,
  'data'=>http_build_query($this->request->data),
  'method'=>'POST',
  ```

  )
  );
- `'url' => $this->passedArgs` To post back all named arguments, when pagination links are clicked.
- `'data'=>http_build_query($this->request->data)` To post back all post data, when pagination links are clicked.