# Pagination through ajax and showing post on the same page

Tags: ajax, cakephp, controller, pagination, cakephp-2.0

I am new to Cakephp, and I m stuck with this thing.
my code is working properly but now i need some modification in my code.
when I try to paginate my view through different pages it works but as each page fetch 20 posts only, to see the next posts i change the page.
Now the 1st 20 post is in my view and on the click of a button using ajax i want to show the next 20 post on the same page (I don't want to redirct to pages to see all the comment) 
plz help...

this is the action that i call to show the view of different pages.

```
        public function view($slug) {

    $topic = $this->Topic->getBySlug($slug);
    $user_id = $this->Auth->user('id');
    $post_count = $topic['Topic']['post_count'];


    $this->paginate['Post']['conditions'] = array('Post.topic_id' => $topic['Topic']['id']);

    if ($this->RequestHandler->isRss()) {
        $this->set('posts', $this->paginate('Post'));
        $this->set('topic', $topic);
        return;
    }

    if (!empty($this->request->data['Poll']['option'])) {
        $this->Topic->Poll->vote($topic['Poll']['id'], $this->request->data['Poll']['option'], $user_id);
        $this->Topic->deleteCache(array('Topic::getBySlug', $slug));
        $this->redirect(array('plugin' => 'forum', 'controller' => 'topics', 'action' => 'view', $slug));

    }

    $this->ForumToolbar->markAsRead($topic['Topic']['id']);
    $this->Topic->increaseViews($topic['Topic']['id']);

    $this->ForumToolbar->pageTitle($topic['Topic']['title']);
    $this->set('topic', $topic);
    $this->set('posts', $this->paginate('Post'));

    $this->render('view_new');
}
```

Comment: Your question doesn't show what you're trying inside the 'View' and doesn't show the JavaScript for the AJAX? Have a look at this question, it may be an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9328621/ajax-paging-sorting-in-cakephp-2-0

Comment: sir i dont know what to write in the Ajax to make that work. i need the ajax of this.

Comment: StackOverflow is not meant to have others write your code *for you* (read the [faq]). The other answer includes a link to the manual: [AJAX Pagination](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/js.html#ajax-pagination), which may do what you want to do. In any case, you should really try to learn JavaScript, jQuery to get started.

Answer (score 0):

I was also looking for ajax pagination few time ago.

After a long search i found a solution, which i have posted at the link mentioned below.

[Ajax pagination with filters in cakephp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13429722/ajax-pagination-with-filters-in-cakephp/13639203#13639203)